# How to retrieve selected time zones in android 4.2 world clock?

Tags: android

Android 4.2 introduced a new world clock.

The world clock lets you check the time in different cities right from the Clock app or your lock screen.

There is a way, or API to retrieve the selected time zones?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, there is no way. The cities are stored as shared preferences of the Clock app.

See [the Cities class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/worldclock/Cities.java) that deals with reading and writing the prefs. The file is MODE_PRIVATE.

The only way to use this is by using reflection - which I cannot recommend!

What's a bit annoying: There is an update event broadcast (see the [onPause() method of CitiesActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/worldclock/CitiesActivity.java)) - but it doesn't contain any data.